# Indentation error : unexpected error

Tags: python

I am new to Python and have written a code in notepad++. I have used spaces instead of tab and I guess I have used the correct indentation format. But I still get thie error. I dont understand what am I doing wrong. Here is the code,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import shutil
import sys

def Usage() :
  print "LabelFile TranscriptionFile PhonemeFile"

def main(argv = None) :
  if len(sys.argv) !=3 :
    Usage()
  else :
    LabelFile = sys.argv[1]
    TranscriptionFile = sys.argv[2]
    PhonemeFile = sys.argv[3]
    if (os.path.exists(LabelFile)) :
      InFile = open(LabelFile, "r")
      TFile = open(TranscriptionFile, "w")
      PFile = open(PhonemeFile, "w")
        for line in iter(InFile) :
          list = line.split()
          Tlist = list.pop(3) 
          Plist = list[2]
          TFile.write(" ".join(list) + "\n") 
          PFile.write("".join(list) + " ")  
        InFile.close()
        TFile.close()
        PFile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
  sys.exit(main())
```

Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an indentation too much in front of

```
for line in iter(InFile) :
```

Reduce the indentation for that line and the following eight lines, and you should be all set.

Comment: It shows the error on line 15 which is TranscriptionFile = sys.argv[2]

Comment: @Shivani Are you 100% sure that you aren't using tabs instead of spaces on that line?

Comment: I am using spaces and I got rid of the indentation error. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

line 21:

```
for line in iter(InFile) :
```

start aligning it with the line above

Tracebacks also tell you error line number so it's quite easy to fix if you read 'em all

Moreover it's a good habit to indent 4 spaces and not 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import shutil
import sys

def Usage() :
    print "LabelFile TranscriptionFile PhonemeFile"

def main(argv = None) :
    if len(sys.argv) !=3 :
        Usage()
    else :
        LabelFile = sys.argv[1]
        TranscriptionFile = sys.argv[2]
        PhonemeFile = sys.argv[3]
        if (os.path.exists(LabelFile)) :
            InFile = open(LabelFile, "r")
            TFile = open(TranscriptionFile, "w")
            PFile = open(PhonemeFile, "w")
            for line in iter(InFile) :
                list = line.split()
                Tlist = list.pop(3) 
                Plist = list[2]
                TFile.write(" ".join(list) + "\n") 
                PFile.write("".join(list) + " ")  
            InFile.close()
            TFile.close()
            PFile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
  sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

First off. Although it's not a requirement, it's commonplace using **four spaces** to indent, not two (unless, of course, you are extending some code that already has 2 spaces indentations)

Then, your amended code (there was an indentation error on the `for` loop on line 21):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import shutil
import sys

def Usage() :
  print "LabelFile TranscriptionFile PhonemeFile"

def main(argv = None) :
  if len(sys.argv) !=3 :
    Usage()
  else :
    LabelFile = sys.argv[1]
    TranscriptionFile = sys.argv[2]
    PhonemeFile = sys.argv[3]
    if (os.path.exists(LabelFile)) :
      InFile = open(LabelFile, "r")
      TFile = open(TranscriptionFile, "w")
      PFile = open(PhonemeFile, "w")
      for line in iter(InFile) :
        list = line.split()
        Tlist = list.pop(3)
        Plist = list[2]
        TFile.write(" ".join(list) + "\n")
        PFile.write("".join(list) + " ")
      InFile.close()
      TFile.close()
      PFile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
  sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

With notepad++, in "settings/preferences" menu, "Edit components" panel, there is an option Tab size, use 4, and a checkbox "replace by space" Check it and you will avoid mixing of tabs and spaces.